# Link html buttons to user registration form

Tags: python, html, css, django, forms

My login forms are working properly but are not connected to the html button. The page with this button is on another url different from the accounts page. How do i link it with the app for accounts or folder containing my html forms. Is there a way of inheriting the app folder into this main folder or inporting just to have a link.

Comment: From what I could understand, you want to submit the form by clicking on a button that is on a different URL altogether, which isn't possible. For a button to trigger submit, it should be on the same page as the form. If your use case is something else, you might need to give a more clear/detailed description and perhaps include a code snippet if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

in link just used {% url 'app_name:name' %}

here app_name = in urls.py file
and name is path name.